# madvise managing memory mapped files

Tags: c, mmap

I have a program that processes a large dataset consisting of a large number (300+) of sizable memory (40MB+) mapped files. All the files are needed together though they are accessed in a sequential way. at the moment I am memory mapping the files and then using `madvise` with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` since I don't want the thing to be any more of a memory hog than it needs to be (without any `madvise` the consumption becomes a problem). The problem it that the program runs much slower (like 50x slower) than the diskio of the system would indicate it should, and becomes worse faster than linearly. as the number of files are involved are increased. Processing 100 files is more than 10x faster than 300 files despite being only 3x the data. I suspect that the memory mapped files are generating a page fault every time a 4kb page is crossed, net result disk seek time is greater than disk transfer time.

Can anyone think of a better way than using `madvise` with `MADV_WILLNEED` and `MADV_DONTNEED` every so often, and if this is the best way, any ideas as to how far to look ahead?

Comment: How are you measuring "memory usage" for judging whether your program is a "memory hog"? Measuring correctly is almost impossible; certainly examining the RSS is not a good indicator. Have you observed that your program is causing other things to get swapped badly when you don't use `madvise`? Or are you just looking at the output of the `free`(1) command?

Comment: Primarily RSS, confirmed with a few instances of unresponsive systems. Removing the madvise doesn't make much difference to the primary point of the question though. The slowdown effect is pretty much the same.